# How to get a list of drive files that are orphaned

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to get a list of files in my drive that have been orphaned. I tried using the search term `is:orphaned` but I just get :
`Invalid argument: q (line 56, file "Code")`

Does anyone know the right search term for searching orphaned drive files in apps script?

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `a list of files in my drive that have been orphaned`. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: @Tanaike Files that have no parent folders. Rafa Guillermos answer seems to be what I am looking for

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about your situation. You want to retrieve the files which have no parents using the search query. For this situation, do you need a workaround?

Comment: @Tanaike it's not super urgent as I can do it in the UI, I was mostly looking at apps script for automation. Is it possible with Htmlservice?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand `Htmlservice` you are thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently not possible to list orphaned files using the Drive API or the `DriveApp` method in Apps Script.

You can find the list of available search queries and terms for the Drive API [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms). While there is a `parents` file query term, this is for finding files with parents of a specific ID as shown in the [files resource documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files).

You can head to [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106) to file a Feature Request for this though, which will let Google know that this is a desired feature of the API.

Comment: Thanks I will do that